# Exception during ingestion, MLRunAccessDeniedError

Tags: python, mlops, feature-store, mlrun

I got this issue during data ingest/write:

```
~/.pythonlibs/jist-jupyter/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlrun/errors.py in raise_for_status(response, message)
     82             raise STATUS_ERRORS[response.status_code](
     83                 error_message, response=response
---> 84             ) from exc
     85         except KeyError:
     86             raise MLRunHTTPError(error_message, response=response) from exc

MLRunAccessDeniedError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://mlrun-api:8080/api/v1/projects/fs-test/feature-sets/test/references/latest?versioned=False: Failed storing feature-set fs-test/test details: {'reason': "MLRunAccessDeniedError('Not allowed to create resource /projects/fs-test/feature-sets/test')"}
```

It is source code, that generated this issue:

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.projects as prj
import mlrun.feature_store as fstore
from mlrun.datastore.targets import ParquetTarget,CSVTarget, NoSqlTarget

...
feature_set=fstore.FeatureSet(name=fsName, entities=entity_list,
                          timestamp_key='sysdate')
feature_set.set_targets(targets=[ParquetTarget(name="s1")],with_defaults=False)
feature_set.save()
```

Do you know, how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about access right management and you can not create/save FeatureSet in project, because you do not have enough privileges. There are at least two solutions:

**1 - Setup project owner**

- Create new project, where you will be in role project owner (in this case you have ability to create/save new FeatureSet), see
- [image]

**2 - Add member of project**

- You have to add your account as new member to the existing project in relevant roles (Admin or Editor), see
- [image]

Precondition: Before focus on these two solutions, please check your current roles, if you have roles Data and Developer at least.